# Cloud computing platform advice?

Tags: virtual-machines, cloud

I'm not new to Linux servers but I am new to virtualisation and cloud computing platforms. I'm looking for a system that I can deploy Linux instances (Debian web servers) across a range of hosts in different data centers.

I have looked into OpenNebula and OpenStack Compute. What would you guys recommend to start testing with and what is the easiest to set up and expand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally like XenServer(different to Xen),as it is easy to install and setup resource pools,remote storage and,livemotion(migration) and it supports a wide variety of hosts. You could also look at VMware ESXi.